# Interact with lower widget in Stack

Tags: flutter

I have a Stack that has a GoogleMap and an overlapping SingleChildScrollView, filled with Widgets.

However, the SCSV now block the map, and I can't interact with it? What I am trying to do, is a map as "upper" widget on the page and then the scrollview can be scrolled over the map.

```
Stack(children: <Widget>[
          Container(
              height: 400,
              child: GoogleMap(
                onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
                initialCameraPosition:
                    CameraPosition(target: _center, zoom: 13.0),
              )),
          SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 300, 0, 0),
                  child: Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white),
                      child: Column(children: _offers))))
        ])
```

Any idea how I can make this happen? Other suggestions than my existing layout are more than welcome, as long as the results is the same :)

Comment: if i understood correctly, you want to dynamically change the order of stack?

Comment: @HarshBhikadia well, I just want to be able to move the map around. But can’t interact with it now as the scroll view (or the padding) is on top so it won’t let me

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you encountered a similar issue to the one I resolved in my application. I had two interactive widgets stacked on top of each other in the photo preview, which were the pan and draw widgets. I wanted to enable users to switch between the two widgets' interactions. Since both the widgets were full-screen, I needed to make the "top" widget transparent for the user's clicks, depending on a boolean flag (in my case, `panEnable`). To address this, I used the [IgnorePointer](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/IgnorePointer-class.html) widget:

```
class PhotoPreviewScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  _PhotoPreviewScreen createState() => _PhotoPreviewScreen();
}

class _PhotoPreviewScreen extends State<PhotoPreviewScreen>  {
  bool  panEnable = true; // THAT IS THE enable/disable flag
  final String imagePath = 'my_image.jpg'; // image to show and interact with

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {     
      return Scaffold(
          body: Stack(
            children: [
                InteractiveViewer( // This is the "lower widget"
                  panEnabled: panEnable, // THAT IS THE enable/disable flag
                  scaleEnabled: panEnable,  // THAT IS THE enable/disable flag
                  boundaryMargin: EdgeInsets.all(double.infinity), 
                  minScale: 1,
                  maxScale: 16,
                  child: Image.file(
                    File(imagePath), // imagePath — local path to an image in Preview
                  ),
                ),
                Center(
                  child: Stack(
                    children: <Widget>[
                           IgnorePointer(
                             ignoring: panEnable,  // THAT IS THE enable/disable flag
                             child:
                                 SomeFullScreenActionWidget( // AN UPPER ACTION
                                   onPressed: () => <SOME ACTION>,
                                   ), // SomeFullScreenActionWidget
                             ), //  IgnorePointer
                           // <here might be some "passive" widgets that are not use pointers
                          ], // children of Stack widget
                 ), // Stack
                ), // Center
                IconButton( // wrap it in Align/Positioned or any other widget to arrange the widgets switch button on the screen
                  iconSize: 33.0,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  icon: Icon(!panEnable? CupertinoIcons.pencil_outline:   CupertinoIcons.pencil_slash), // I use some stylish icons, you may choose standard
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      panEnable = !panEnable; // HERE IS THE SWITCH enable/disable flag
                      }); // SetState
                    }, // onPressed
                  ), // IconButton
               ], // children of Stack
              ),  // Stack
             ); // Scaffold
```

It is important to note that I used a `StatefulWidget` class to utilize `setState()`. If a `StatelessWidget` class were used instead, it would not function properly.